# first letter of text box

Tags: c#

how to check entered value in text box have B as first letter using c#

Comment: WebForms? Winforms? WPF? MVC?

Comment: Do you need to check as the user is typing or on some sort of submit event?

Comment: This is a very trivial question. You should be spending more time on C# tutorials.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to StackOverflow, please review the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).  I'd also suggest you read [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) for hints on how to ask better questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
if(myTextBox.Text.StartsWith("B")) ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I will think this is the most efficient

```
if (myTextBox.Text.Length > 0 && myTextBox.Text[0] == 'B')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static string UppercaseFirst(string UpperCase)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UpperCase))
   {
      return string.Empty;
   }

   return char.ToUpper(UpperCase[0]) + UpperCase.Substring(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach `TextChanged` event and check first letter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the string `StartsWith()` method.

```
if("Bar".StartsWith("B")) // ....
if(Textbox.Text.StartsWith("B")) // ....
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to just go in to **textbox's property** after that in that you see **Text** their you just give there that **CHAR** what you want to see.